# Spring JMS Websphere MQ open input count issue

Tags: spring, jms, ibm-mq

I am using Spring 3.2.8 with JDK 6 and Websphere MQ 7.5.0.5.  In my application I am making some jms calls using jmsTemplate via ThreadPool.  First I faced condition that "Current queue depth" count increases as I hit jms calls.  I tracked all objects I am initiating via ThreadPool and interrupt or cancel all threads/future objects.  So this "Current queue depth" count controlled.

Now problem is "Open input count" value increases nearly to the number of requests I am sending.  When I stops my server this count becomes 0.

In all this case I am able to send request and get response till count of 80 and my ThreadPool size is 30.  After reaching request count somewhere to 80 I keep receiving error of future object rejections and not able to receive responses.  In fact null responses receive for remaining calls.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using queue in my application and filter on correlation id has been applied.  I read more on it and found when we make a call to `jmsTemplate.receiveSelected (queue, filter)` then this has serious impact on performance.  Once I removed this filter the thread conjunction issue resolved.  But now filtering is still a problem for me.

Now I will be applying filter in a different way with some limitation of the application but not using `receiveSelected` instead now I am using `jmsTemplate.receive`.

### Update on 14-Sep

All - I find this as a solution and like to post here.

One of my colleague helped in rectifying this issue which is great help.  What we observed after debugging that if cacheConsumer is true then based on combination of

> queue + message-selector + session

consumers are cached by Spring.  And even calling `close()` method does not do any thing; basically empty method and causing thread to be hanged/stuck.

After setting cacheConsumer to false, I reverted my code back to original i.e. `jmsTemplate.receiveSelected (destination, messageSelector)`, now when I hit 100 request count of threads only increased between 5 to 10 during multiple iterations of test.

So - this property need to be used carefully.

hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

> First I faced condition that "Current queue depth" count increases as
>   I hit jms calls. I tracked all objects I am initiating via ThreadPool
>   and interrupt or cancel all threads/future objects.

I have no idea what you are talking about but you should NOT be using/monitoring the 'current queue depth' value from your application.  Bad, bad design.  Only MQ monitoring tools should be using it.

> Now problem is "Open input count" value increases nearly to the number
>   of requests I am sending. When I stops my server this count becomes 0.

Bad programming.  You are 'opening a queue then putting a message' over and over and over again.  How about you put some code to CLOSE the queue or better yet, REUSE the open queue!!!!!!!

Comment: Hey Roger, sorry my bad I could not explain much in my question but what you stated is not correct.  

 - If you see implementation of jmsTemplate then closing and opening connection is done by Spring and I am using CachingConnectionFactory which does reuse of connection.  
 - And I am not monitoring queue using my application but using Websphere MQ Explorer tool.